# Tengo problemas para comparar tipos de variable en mi código JS

Tags: javascript, comparaciones

En un ejercicio de clase me han pedido que calcule el área del círculo y la longitud de la circunferencia haciendo que el usuario introduzca el valor del radio. El programa hará su función sin problemas a menos de que el usuario NO introduzca un número, entonces tendré que comunicar el error y pedir de nuevo el dato.

El problema es que hice el código y todo funcionaba bien, pero lo he vuelto a probar y no me acepta como ningún dato introducido un número. Dejo por aquí mi código

```js
var radio;

do{

    radio = prompt("Introduzca el valor del radio");

    
    if(radio != Number){
        
        alert("Introduzca un número");

    }

}while(radio != Number) 

if( radio == Number){

    alert("El área del círculo es: "+parseInt(radio)**2 * Math.PI)
    alert("La longitud de la circunferencia: "+ parseInt(radio)*2*Math.PI)

}
```

Comment: podrias intentar `while(!parseFloat(radio))`

Comment: Las dos condiciones pueden ser `if/while(isNaN(radio))`.

Comment: @JackNavaRow funciona perfectamente con tus indicaciones  Gracias

Comment: @PabloLozano Yo al principio hice el código con la función isNaN() pero me fallaba a la hora de dar una respuesta vacía es decir, pulsar enter sin haber escrito nada en la consola. Calculaba el área y la longitud con resultado NaN  Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo he "arreglado". Les dejo el código para que le echen un vistazo y vosotros, los verdaderos profesionales opinéis xD

```js
var radio;

do{

    radio = prompt("Introduzca el valor del radio");

    
    if(!Number(radio)){
        
        alert("Introduzca un número");

    }

}while(!Number(radio)) 

if(Number(radio)){

    alert("El área del círculo es: "+parseInt(radio)**2 * Math.PI)
    alert("La longitud de la circunferencia: "+ parseInt(radio)*2*Math.PI)

}
```

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], edita y agrega ¿qué modificaste?, ya que responder con solo código se considera de baja calidad

Answer (score 1):

`Number` en JS es una función, por ello la igualdad `radio == Number` nunca se cumple. Podrías utilizar en su lugar la función `isNaN`.

Por otro lado no es necesario que vuelvas a comprobar fuera del bucle si el radio es un número.

```js
do{
    radio = prompt("Introduzca el valor del radio");
    if(!radio || isNaN(radio)){
        alert("Introduzca un número");
    }

} while(!radio || isNaN(radio)) 

alert("El área del círculo es: " + parseInt(radio)**2 * Math.PI)
alert("La longitud de la circunferencia: " + parseInt(radio)* 2 * Math.PI)
```

Comment: Yo al principio hice el código con la función isNaN(), pero el problema que tenía con ella es que cuando no introducía nada o un/os espacio/s, me saltaba fuera del bucle y me "calculaba" el área y la longitud sin dato.  Cito textualmente lo que me pone: "El área del círculo es: NaN" / "La longitud de la circunferencia es: NaN".    En cuanto a la comprobación fuera del bucle tienes razón, ha sido un error de novato.  Gracias

Comment: Lo modifico para que evalúe si se ha introducido algún valor

Comment: Una observación: en muchos navegadores **es usual** que cuando una página lanza varias alertas sucesivas desde js **se dispare una alerta preguntando si se da permiso para ello**. Y en caso de que el usuario niegue el permiso los scripts dejan de ser funcionales. Es recomendable usar un mecanismo diferente de `alert()` (ej: dialogo modal de Bootstrap) para ese tipo de interacciones.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que involuntariamente has generado un ciclo infinito, no identifico el lenguaje que estas usando para programar, pero me llama la atencion este linea `}while(radio != Number)` creo que esto te genera un bucle.

Saludos

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], el lenguaje que usa es JavaScript

Comment: Te lo confirmo, me genera un bucle bastante infinito jajajajjajajja.        Gracias

Comment: Excelente que lo pudiste resolver, Saludos